# how setup sql server user for connection string aceess?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

probably something trivial but I cannot figure it out. I created database in SQL Server 2012 and want to be able access it through connection string (excel vba code) from other computers like that:

```
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SQLSRV01;Initial Catalog=TESTDB ;User Id=test; Password=xxx"
```

I created user test on sql server and gave him read rights etc and I got runtime error login failed for user test. What privileges should have such user? Should be a windows user as well?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a more generic connection string construction and tighten up the string declarations (remove trailing spaces).

```
con.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=SQLSRV01;Database=TESTDB;UID=test;PWD=xxx;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change SQLSRV01 to .\SQLSRV01 if you are running the SQL Server on your local computer.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was going something trivial, this sql serer instance was configured as windows authentication only. I have change to both windows ans sql and works.
thanks